# Does a 5A Car Fuse Blows in a 12 Miliseconds Peak of 6A, in a 220v Circuit?

Tags: fuses, circuit-breaker

Thinking here in using a 5A fuse in a certain circuit, but it may reach 6A sometimes for a mather of 10 or 12 miliseconds only.

That way, would this fuse blow or it would sustain and blow only in given time?

[image: It's this kind of fuse. And yes, it is in a 220v circuit.]

Comment: Not an answer, but for safety reasons, do not use a 12V car fuse in a 220V circuit, as it is not rated to such voltages.

Comment: There are "fast" and "slow blow" fuses and their datasheets should tell you what to expect in terms of overcurrent and time. A 5A slow blow 220V fuse is *probably* what you are looking for.

Comment: Just added an image of the fuse. And yes, it is a 220v circuit.

Comment: That fuse is designed to break and provide isolation on a 12 V supply. It is not rated and is not suitable for 220 V DC or AC.

Comment: What happens if I use it in a 220v circuit?

Comment: The fuse never opens? It explodes? It catches on fire and explodes?

Comment: For the same reason you don't use a 220 volt fuse in a 20000 volt circuit. Fuse is meant to stop current flowing when it breaks. At 220 volts it may fail to extinguish the arc because the terminals are so close to each other so current may keep flowing for too long, igniting something or killing someone. These fuses are for cars, not 220V mains circuits!

Comment: It'd be like trying to use a paper plate to stop a bullet.

Answer (score 2):

Some fuses are faster than others but it would be unthinkable for a fuse to blow that quickly at such a small overload.

DO NOT use an automotive fuse to protect a mains circuit though. A mains circuit has far far higher fault-energies available than a car does.